# Creating number pattern (triangle numbers) in c++ with minimum loops

Tags: c++, loops, iteration

We were asked to make a triangular no. pattern in c++ with min. loops. The triangle pattern is as follows:

```
____1_____
___2__3____
__4__5__6__
7__8__9__10
```

**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
    int n=0, r=0, i=0;
    cout << "No. of rows: ";
    cin >> r;

    for( n=1; n<=r; n++) {
        for( i=1; i<=r-n; i++) {
            cout << "  ";
        }
        for( i=(n*(n-1)/2)+1; i<=(n*(n+1)/2); i++ ) {
            if( i<10 )
                cout << " " << i << "  ";
            else
                cout << i << "  ";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**QUESTIONS**

**1)** Is it wise to use pattern generating formulas? for eg, for putting value of i in last loop, i used the formula for the pattern **1,2,4,7 ..** as **(n*(n-1)/2)+1**. Is it more efficient this way? what could be an **iterative** approach? and what could be a possible **recursive** one?

**2)** Is it possible to reduce no. of loops? is it better to reduce variables or reduce loops?

THANK YOU!

Comment: " is it better to reduce variables or reduce loops?" profile and see

Comment: @ChrisBeck How do we profile?

Comment: @TimKrul, using a profiler, of course! For example, you can use _gprof_.

Comment: You may be able to reduce a loop by using the `std::string` class for the spaces.  Look it up (especially how to create a string of duplicate characters).

Answer (score 3):

1. Its a simple incremental number pyramid that dose not require any special formula. Formula's increases the complexity of the program because more calculations are involved. Try to keep the code simple.

Simplest way to do this is :

```
int main() {
int num,i=1;
cout<<"Enter Number of Rows";
cin>>num;
 for(int r=1; r<=num; r++)
 {
  for(int space=1; space<=num-r; space++){
    cout<<"  ";
    }
  for(int c=1; c<=r; c++,i++){
   cout<<"  "<<i;
   }
  cout<<"\n";
 }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a completely personal opinion, but I think that using formulae is really not going to affect the efficiency, since you are anyways printing the elements one at a time. So the total time is dependent on your length of input which is `r(r+1)/2`.

I wrote this and it seems to work good too, though the logic in this code is to just keep printing the elements in order and breaking the line when required. It uses only one inner loop to print the spaces at the beginning of each line. Here is the Ideone [link](https://ideone.com/ZG1IfT).

```
int r;
cin>>r;                             //number of rows
int spaces = r-1, rowcount = 1;
int curcount = 0;

for(int i=1; i<=(r*(r+1))>>1;i++) {

    if(curcount == 0) {
        for(int j=0; j<spaces; j++)
            cout<<" ";
        spaces--;
    }

    cout<<(i<10?" ":"")<<i<<" ";
    if(++curcount == rowcount) {
        rowcount++;
        curcount=0;
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```